# What triggers new issues detected in GSC?

Tags: google-search-console

I'm curious what triggers new issues in Google Search Console for existing content?

For example, I have received several alerts this past week for pages that have had no issues for a couple of years.  Now there are issues with mobile font size, items too close together, FAQ and video schema.  I understand that newer pages can trigger these messages, but why does a page that receives plenty of traffic and has existed for many months suddenly trigger one of these messages?

Is this due to an algorithm change, or a change in my audience's browser/devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm convinced after a few weeks of watching these issues arise, that this is an issue with Google's algorithm.

I had several pages show up with errors in GSC after several months without any errors.  Then the `mobile font size` and `items too close together` errors showed up about a week ago, and then after a couple of days, disappeared.  Additionally, GSC reports that most of my pages have a problem with Cumulative Layout Shift being > 1.  However, when I use Google Page Speed Insights, these pages show 0 for CLS.  I'm guessing Google's QA process had a little hiccup and nothing more.

Comment: It seems more likely to be an issue with the field data to me.  Google doesn't seem to have a large enough sample of users to actually tell if most of my pages are mobile friendly or not with field data.    And yet Google is using the field data ([Will Google use field or lab data for ranking sites with core web vitals performance metrics?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/132919/will-google-use-field-or-lab-data-for-ranking-sites-with-core-web-vitals-perform)).   It seems that a single user with weird browser settings may be enough to trigger warnings in GSC.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, thanks.  It could very well be one or two users who trigger the warnings given the relatively small site I run.